# Displaying custom field in dokan vendor Dashboard Orders

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, dokan

I created a custom fields on WooCommerce for the orders and customers then I need to show the vendors this fields in Vendors Dashboard dokan orders, thanks for you help